# Accessing child component data vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I access a child component data from the parent component?
I have a parent component "MissionPlanner" which i want to access the child component "ChosenHeroes" array called "chosenHeroes". I want to ultimately render a div if an element is in that array - and be able to update the array in the parent

I am not sure if i should be using emit() and how exactly to use it. I tried making a custom event "addHero" and pass that back. But i am getting errors

ChosenHeroes.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="chosenHero">
      <!-- placeholder value -->
      <option :value="null">Select a hero</option>

      <!-- available heroes -->
      <option v-for="hero in heroes"
              :key="hero.name"
              :value="hero.name">
        {{ hero.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <button @click="addHero(chosenHero)"
            :disabled="chosenHero === null || chosenHeroes.length >= 3">Add Hero</button>
    <br>
    <h3>Chosen Heroes</h3>
    <div class="chosen-heroes">
      <div v-for="(hero, i) in chosenHeroes"
           :key="hero.name">
        <strong>Slot {{ i + 1 }}:</strong>
        <Hero :hero="hero"
              @removeHero="removeHero(hero)" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hero from "./Hero";

export default {
  components: {
    Hero
  },
  props: {
    "heroes": Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chosenHero: null,
      chosenHeroes: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addHero(name) {
      if(this.chosenHeroes.length < 3) {
        this.chosenHeroes.push({ name });
        this.chosenHero = null;
      }
      this.$emit("add-hero",this.chosenHeroes);
    },

    removeHero(hero) {
      this.chosenHeroes = this.chosenHeroes.filter(h => h.name != hero.name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

HeroPlanner.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- justice leage application begins here -->
    <h1 id="jl">Justice League Mission Planner</h1>

    <ul class="roster">
      <h3>Roster:</h3>
      <li v-for="hero in heroes"
          :key="hero.name">

        <!-- to do: conditionally display this span -->
        <span v-if="isInList(hero.name)">✔ &nbsp;</span>

        <span>{{ hero.name }}&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="edit"
              @click="editHero(hero)">edit</span>
      </li>
      <br>
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="new name"
             v-model="newName"
             v-if="isEdit"
             @keyup.enter="changeName"
             @blur="clear">
      <br>
      <span v-if="isEdit">enter to submit, click outside the box to cancel</span>
    </ul>
    <chosen-heroes :heroes="heroes" :chosenHeroes="chosenHeroes" @add-hero="addHero" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChosenHeroes from "./components/ChosenHeroes.vue";

export default {
  components: {
   "chosen-heroes" : ChosenHeroes
  },
  data() {
    return {
      heroes: [
        { name: "Superman" },
        { name: "Batman" },
        { name: "Aquaman" },
        { name: "Wonder Woman" },
        { name: "Green Lantern" },
        { name: "Martian Manhunter" },
        { name: "Flash" }
      ],
      newName: "",
      isEdit: false,
      heroToModify: null,
      chosenHeroes: ChosenHeroes.data
    };
  },
  methods: {
...isInList(heroName) {
      return this.chosenHeroes.map(heroObject => heroObject.name).includes(heroName);
    }
```

And here are the errors I got when i ran it:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.chosenHeroes.map is not a function"

found in

---> <MissionPlanner> at src/MissionPlanner.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: this.chosenHeroes.map is not a function
    at VueComponent.isInList (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/MissionPlanner.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:78)
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"aeb9565a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/MissionPlanner.vue?vue&type=template&id=e2c8c042&scoped=true& (app.js:946), <anonymous>:21:19)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2630)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"aeb9565a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/MissionPlanner.vue?vue&type=template&id=e2c8c042&scoped=true& (app.js:946), <anonymous>:19:15)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
```

I went through [this article here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-emit-data-in-vue-beyond-the-vuejs-documentation) on the emit() and how to emit data from child components to the parent components but I am not sure I used it properly

Comment: You seem to be calling a function that doesn't exist - `this.chosenHeroes.map` in `MissionPlanner`. Also, in `HeroPlanner` `@add-hero="addHero"` - what is `addHero`?

Comment: @Still_learning so the "addHero" is a function/method in the child component that adds new heroes to the list of chosenHeroes. And i want access to that list in my parent component- in the article linked it mention something about "emit()" but not sure about how to use it

I am then trying to map over the chosenHeroes list/array and checking that the Hero object is in that array

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Answer (score 0):

Change `@add-hero="addHero"` to `@add-hero="anyMethodName"`
and create a method:

```
anyMethodName(value) {
    //do what you want with the chosenHeroes
}
```

`value` is the `chosenHeroes` that was passed through from the child component.

See link for example: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201/2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from child to parent you can pass a parent's method as a prop to the child:

PARENT TEMPLATE SECTION

```
  <child-component :dataHandler="dataHandler">
  </child-component>
```

PARENT METHOD IN SCRIPT METHODS SECTION

```
dataHandler (input) {
  // handle your new data in parent component
}
```

CHILD SCRIPT PROPS SECTION

`props: ["dataHandler"]`

register your prop. You can use dataHandler in child as normal method and pass there new data as argument - the method will be executed in parent, but with the data you provided as argument in the child.

The error that you are getting suggests that chosenHeroes is not an array (maybe it's undefined?).

Answer (score 0):

The `$emit` will work when it is called, and in parent, it will be same as events (firing only when events are happened). In this case, you need the data from the child always render a div in the parent (if what I understand is correct).

It is better to use the `Vuex` store for your purpose. You can sync the data into the `store` from the child component. Since the `store` data is global, it is accessible from all components.